# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed

Tags: java, string, loops

I got the following code, but after the first loop, my debugger is giving following errors,it s strange, i did it all the time like that, but it doesnt work anymore, this is pretty strange?!
I checked it step-by-step, it is just stoppen after the switch order?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed
        at java.util.Scanner.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.findWithinHorizon(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)
        at Level.schleife(Level.java:35)
        at Crawler.main(Crawler.java:23)
```

---

```
public boolean schleife() {
    System.out.println("Das Spiel beginnt, bewege Dich mit der WASD Steuerung!");
    Scanner eingabeMove = new Scanner(System.in);

    tmpi = positioni;
    tmpj = positionj;
    while (true) {
        String bewegung = eingabeMove.nextLine();
        switch (bewegung) {
            case "w": {                                        // vorwärts
                tmpi += 1;
                if (actionResult()) {
                    positioni = tmpi;
                    break;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            case "a": {                                    // links
                tmpj -= 1;
                if (actionResult()) {
                    positionj = tmpj;
                    break;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            case "s": {                                    // rückwärts
                tmpi -= 1;
                if (actionResult()) {
                    positioni = tmpi;
                    break;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            case "d": {                                    // rechts
                tmpj += 1;
                if (actionResult()) {
                    positionj = tmpj;
                    break;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            default: {                                    // falsche Eingabe
                System.out.println("Falsche Eingabe!");
                continue;
            }
        }
        eingabeMove.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: move `eingabeMove.close()` down 3 lines outside of the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Don't call `eingabeMove.close();` at the end of that `while` loop. You're causing the Scanner to become inoperable at the end of the first loop.

Since the loop always terminates with a `return`, it doesn't make sense to close the Scanner in this `schleife()` method.

You actually don't need to close the Scanner though, because it wraps `System.in` which never closes anyhow. Given this fact, you can simply let `eingabeMove` go out of scope when the `schleife()` returns.

If you really want to close the Scanner, you should pass `eingabeMove` as a parameter to the method, and close it from the calling method.

```
public boolean schleife(Scanner eingabeMove) {
   // use the scanner
}
```

Calling code:

```
Scanner eingabeMove = new Scanner(System.in);
schleife(eingabeMove);
eingabeMove.close();
```

Comment: actually it should be called, just 1 line down outside of the loop braces

Comment: @ControlAltDel thanks, I caught that after he made the edit to include the whole method

Comment: Actually, if you move the `close` outside the while loop, it will never get called, since the only way to leave the loop is by one of the return statements.

Comment: @Eran lol good point. So if he wants to close the Scanner, the code needs to be refactored so the Scanner is instantiated by the calling method and passed into this one.

Comment: gknicker I cant use the calling methode, cauze the `schleife` is started in my `main` methode in a different class and the methode `schleife` is defined in a second class...

2 lines down, right is not reachable and 1 doesn't work as well :(

Comment: @kellerprogger you actually don't need to close the Scanner in this case, since `System.in` never really closes. I've modified my answer to include this information.

Comment: @gknicker the point is, that it is not about the closing... wont change the error code. I have been through the while code more than once via debugger, it seems like that the scanner function doesnt work the second time. for example: i pressed "d" first time, the scanner automaticilly sends me to case "d" again? what the hell? never happened to me