# Counting Letters form a Text File

Tags: java, arrays

I want to count the appearance of each letter of the alphabet from a text file. When I run it I get the actual filename in each "letter" and then the program crashes. Not sure what to do.

Sample Text File Input:

Hi, I like to play sports.

Sample Output:

Letters - Frequencies in file:

Number of Occurrence of a is: 1

Number of Occurrence of b is: 0

...

Number of Occurrence of h is: 1

Number of Occurrence of i is: 3

etc.

```
/*
 * program that reads in a text file and counts the frequency of each letter
 * displays the frequencies in descending order
 */

import java.util.*; //needed for Scanner
import java.io.*;  //needed for File related classes
public class LetterCounter {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in); //Scanner to read in file name
    System.out.println("Enter the name of the text file to read:");
    String filename = keyboard.next();

    //This String has all the letters of the alphabet
    //You can use it to "look up" a character using alphabet.indexOf(...) to see what letter it is
    //0 would indicate 'a', 1 for 'b', and so on.  -1 would mean the character is not a letter
    String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    //TODO: create a way to keep track of the letter counts
    //I recommend an array of 26 int values, one for each letter, so 0 would be for 'a', 1 for 'b', etc.
    char[] array = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();

    Scanner fileScan = new Scanner(new File(filename));  //another Scanner to open and read the file
    //loop to read file line-by-line
    while (fileScan.hasNext()) {  //this will continue to the end of the file
      String line = fileScan.nextLine();  //get the next line of text and store it in a temporary String
      line = line.toLowerCase( ); // convert to lowercase

       //print out frequencies
    System.out.println("Letters - Frequencies in file:");

    //TODO: print out all the letter counts
      //TODO: count the letters in the current line
      for (int i = 0; i < filename.length(); i++) { 
            array[i] = filename.charAt(i); 
            int find = 0; 
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) { 

                // If any matches found 
                if (filename.charAt(i) == array[j])  
                    find++;                 
            }
            if (find == 1)  
                System.out.println("Number of Occurrence of " + 
                 filename.charAt(i) + " is:" + filename.charAt(i));
    }
    fileScan.close(); //done with file reading...close the Scanner so the file is "closed"



  }
}
}
```

Comment: *and then the program crashes* If it crashes, you should get an error message, wich is very helpfull for us. Please share the stacktrace

Comment: Once "line" is converted to lowercase, it is not used again. Instead the filename's characters are counted. Is this what you are trying to do. Otherwise, fix code.

Answer (score 2):

In the future, it would be helpful to include the error message as well.

After running it myself, I got

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.ensureOpen(Scanner.java:1150)
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.hasNext(Scanner.java:1439)
        at LetterCounter.main(LetterCounter.java:26)
```

From there, we can see it's a problem with the scanner closing. In fact, Googling that exact error (`IllegalStateException: Scanner closed`) will show you exactly what's wrong, as the first result is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28052519/java-lang-illegalstateexception-scanner-closed), where it says that the Scanner's `.close()` method needs to be *outside* of your `while` loop.

I'm pointing out Google not to shame you, but to show how you can look for solutions yourself so you don't have to wait for other people to come along and explain.

I hope that helps!

(Also, I would recommend testing your code further, as I do not think it is working as you intended based on the output I got.)