# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed on File I/O

Tags: exception, file-io, java.util.scanner, java

I'm currently making a class that allows users to edit the line based on the ID that the user enters. However, I'm having the error below:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed".

Even though I have put a `scanner.close()` below the `int phone input`.
Is there any explanation on why is this happening

```
package com.company;

import javax.sound.midi.SysexMessage;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Edit {
    static Scanner x;

    public static void editRecord() throws ParseException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("ENter your ID");
        String ID = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("ENter your new name");
        String name = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("ENter your new EMail");
        String email = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("ENter your new Address");
        String address = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("ENter your new Date");
        String date = scanner.nextLine();
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        Date userDate = format.parse(date);
        System.out.println("ENter your Gender");
        String gender = scanner.nextLine();
        boolean Gender = Boolean.parseBoolean(gender);
        System.out.println("ENter your new phone number");
        int phone = scanner.nextInt();


        String filepath = "leads.csv";
    String tempfile = "temp.csv";
    File oldFile = new File(filepath);
    File newFile = new File(tempfile);
    String ID1 = ""; String name1 = "";String email1="";String address1 = ""; String userdate1 = "";
    String Gender1 = ""; String phone1 = "";
    scanner.close();
    try{
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempfile,true);
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
        x = new Scanner(new File(filepath));
        x.useDelimiter("[,\n]");

        while (x.hasNext()){
            ID1 = x.next();
            name1 = x.next();
            phone1 = x.next();
            email1 = x.next();
            address1 = x.next();
            userdate1 = x.next();
            Gender1 = x.next();
            if(ID1.equals(ID)){
                pw.println(name+","+phone+","+email+","+address+","+userDate+","+Gender);
            }
            else {
                pw.println(name1+","+phone1+","+email1+","+address1+","+userdate1+","+Gender1);
            }
            x.close();
            pw.flush();
            pw.close();
            oldFile.delete();
            File dump = new File(filepath);
            newFile.renameTo(dump);
        }


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error Occured");
    }


    }
}
```

Comment: see this post hope it will sove your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28052519/java-lang-illegalstateexception-scanner-closed

Answer (score 1):

The **Scanner** initialized over **System.in** to read the user input is fine.
The **IllegalStateException** is thrown from the scanner initialized within the **try block**.

The exception is thrown as you are closing the Scanner within the while loop.
To avoid it move the **x.close()** and **pw.close()** statements to the **finally block** as below,

```
PrintWriter pw = null;
try {
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempfile,true);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    pw = new PrintWriter(bw);
    x = new Scanner(new File(filepath));
    x.useDelimiter("[,\n]");

    while (x.hasNext()){
        ...
        pw.flush();
    }

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Error Occured");
} finally {
    x.close();
    if (pw != null) {
        pw.close();
    }  
}
```

Comment: @Seralathan Hey i did try to follow your instruction but unfortunately, the pw.close() does not recognize unless if i join the try bracket

Comment: @PhạmQuốcMinhĐăng You need the **try**, **catch** and **finally** blocks. **x.close()** and **pw.close()** need to be put to the **finally** block.  Can you share the outcome/error you are facing after moving the **pw.close()** to the finally block.

Comment: @PhạmQuốcMinhĐăng Refer to the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html for the recommended way of closing the **PrintWriter**.

Comment: the pw.close() does not recognize the variable (Cannot resolve symbol 'pw')

Comment: @PhạmQuốcMinhĐăng The **pw** variable's scope is currently only in the scope of the try block. Declare it before the try block so it's available after the block ends. 
`PrintWriter pw = null 
`
Also check for the null value in the finally block before trying to close the PrintWriter.  
`finally {`
    `if (pw != null) {`
       `pw.close();`
    `}`
`}`